# Google maps Satellite view is not showing all labels

Tags: android, google-maps

In my application I'm using google maps Satellite View, but its not showing all labels in my town like in Google Maps Application.
Here is screenshots from my application and from Google Maps Application :

My application :
[My application Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R29Jn.jpg)

Google Maps Application :
[Google Maps Application Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BxANn.jpg)

And here is my code :

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_location_route);
    int status = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(getBaseContext());
    if (status != ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
        int requestCode = 10;
        Dialog dialog = GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(status, this, requestCode);
        dialog.show();
    }
    else{
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    }
}

@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    try {
        mGoogleMap = googleMap;
        mGoogleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID);
        mGoogleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
        Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
        String provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);
        Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
        if (location != null) {
            onLocationChanged(location);
        }
        drawYourMarker(yourLocation);
        drawPharmacyMarker(pharmacyLocation);

        // Checks, whether start and end locations are captured
        if (yourLocation != null && pharmacyLocation != null) {
            String url = getDirectionsUrl(yourLocation, pharmacyLocation);
            DownloadTask downloadTask = new DownloadTask();
            downloadTask.execute(url);
        }
    } catch (SecurityException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Is there any way to make my application show more labels like in Google Maps application ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because Google Maps app use all the available APIs from Google. The API you are looking for is Google Places API to get all the labels.

You have to turn it on on the Google API console and follow this [tutorial](https://developers.google.com/places/android-api/signup?hl=es) to achieve put them on your map.

Hope this help.

Answer (score 1):

You need to change Map Type

```
mGoogleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID);
```

to

```
mGoogleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_SATELLITE);
```